# how to use directive in particular events in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template

I have a html like this ,

```
  <div ng-controller="main">
     <div ng-sparkline class="first"></div>
     <div class="second"></div>
     <div class="third"></div>
     <div class="fourth"><button ng-click="save()">click</button></div>
  </div>
```

this is my template

```
  myApp.directive('ngSparkline', function ()
  {
     return
     {
       template: '<div>Hello! {{name}}</div>',
     };
  });
```

I want to append this template into first (classname) div when i click on click button.I want to append this template for each and every click. how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not think in terms of jQuery when using Angular (I did too in the beginning). The correct solution would be:

- Have an array of things(*) in your `$scope`.
- The `$scope.save()` method adds things(*) to the array.
- Display them as (without using a directive at all):

  ```
  <div class="first">
      <div ng-repeat="thing in arrayOfThings">Hello {{thing.name}}!</div>
  </div>
  ```

If you really want to use the template (I guess it is more complex than shown - sparklines), repeat the template:

```
<div class="first">
    <div ng-repeat="thing in arrayOfThings">
        <div ng-sparkline>..do stuff with thing...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(*) "thing" is your appropriate model object.